# hover function addClass

Tags: jquery

```
$("table.table").hover(function() {
  $('.main-head').toggleClass("hovered");
});
```

This code does work. Though it makes all my `.main-head` elements change, any way to fix this to only change the closest element? I tried adding a `.closest()` and even a `.each(function(){` maybe I did not write them correctly and well I threw em away after seeing them not work.

Any suggestions? The basic markup (just writing off the top of my head)

```
<div class="main-head">
   <div class="title">
     <h2>TITLE</h2>
     </div>
</div>
  <div class="main-content">
   <table class="table">
     <tr>
       <td></td>
     </tr>
   </table>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$("table.table").hover(function() {
    $(this).closest('.main-head').toggleClass("hovered");
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/rWG78/)

---

**UPDATE**

For the changed markup

```
$("table.table").hover(function() {
    $(this).parent().prev('.main-head').toggleClass("hovered");
}); ​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/rWG78/1/)

Comment: +1: I hadn't seen the .closest function yet. Something new to read :)

Comment: @JoelEtherton jQuery has a lot of hidden gems :)

Comment: @JoelEtherton - `closest` will search `$(this).parent()`, and the parent of that element, until it hits a match and returns the element. `find` will search through the children and neighbors.

Comment: @TravisJ: Well yes, now that I know of its existence I can read the documentation on it :) I just had not seen that method before.

Comment: I believe I tried .closest, but I'm not sure if I tried it in this order lol. I believe i tried it with a `.each`

Comment: yeah this did not work either for some reason. I just checked my markup and I'm going to update the original ok

Comment: @user1760670 sure it didn't work - because the HTML markup is different :) I've updated the answer

Comment: yeah I wrote the markup off my head at first. then saw that it was different :/ opps. but thank you for fast reply I'm trying it now.

Comment: Ding Ding Ding we have a winner.The first code I tried though (updated) gave an unexpected token, I rewrote it, I think something happened what I copy and pasted into console.

Answer (score 0):

If it is the very first element you want to toggle, then you can add something like this;

```
    $('.main-head:first').toggleClass("hovered");
```

Comment: there are hundreds of the .main-head :) it parsed through php and it is a forum website. thank you though